# React Native - Handling hardware back button navigates out of the app instead of going to the home screen

Tags: react-native

I'm facing an issue with handling the hardware back button in my React Native app. Currently, when the back button is pressed, it exits the app entirely, and upon reopening, it starts from the home screen. However, my intention is to navigate to the home screen instead.
Here's the relevant code for handling the hardware back button:

```
  function handleBackButton() {
    navigation.navigate(
      REBOOK_ENABLED
        ? Screens.RebookHome
        : EVENTS_ENABLED
        ? Screens.EventHome
        : AA_ENABLED
        ? Screens.AAHome
        : Screens.Home
    );
  }
  
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);

  return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);
}, [returnScreen, navigation]);
```

Verified that the handleBackButton function is being called when the back button is pressed.
Checked the navigation logic, and it appears to be correct.
I expected that pressing the hardware back button would navigate to the home screen of the app, not exit the app entirely. However, this is not the current behavior.